# writing to a text file and reading that text file

Tags: c#

I have used this code

```
 var dest1 = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(_logFolderPath, "log1.txt"));
   dest1.WriteLine(line.Trim());
```

to write to a text file log1.txt after that i have to read this text file...

i have declared in a variable... I know this is not possible..but i dont know how

```
using (var file = File.OpenText(dest1))
```

How to open that text file and read that file by using

```
while ((line2 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Any suggestion??

EDIT:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select codesnippet from edk_custombrsnippet_vw", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            string line = dt.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString().Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine).Replace("\r", Environment.NewLine);
            ;

            //MessageBox.Show(line);

            string Filepath2 = TextBox1.Text;
            int counter = 1;
            string line2;

            if (File.Exists(Filepath2) )
            {
                DirectoryInfo Folder = new DirectoryInfo(textboxPath.Text);
                var _logFolderPath = Path.Combine(textboxPath.Text.Trim(), "log");
                if (Folder.Exists)

                    if (!Directory.Exists(_logFolderPath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(_logFolderPath);

                string filename = Path.Combine(_logFolderPath, "log1.txt");
                var dest1 = File.AppendText(filename);

                    dest1.WriteLine(line.Trim());

                using (var file = File.OpenText(filename))
                {
                    using (var file2 = File.OpenText(Filepath2))
                    {
                        bool time = false;

                        while ((line2 = file2.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            using (var dest = File.AppendText(Path.Combine(_logFolderPath, "log.txt")))
                            {
                                if (!time)
                                {
                                    dest.WriteLine("");
                                    dest.WriteLine("---------------------" + DateTime.Now + "---------------------");
                                    time = true;
                                }
                                bool patternwritten = false;
                                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    if (line.IndexOf(line2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                                    {
                                        if (!patternwritten)
                                        {
                                            dest.WriteLine("");
                                            dest.WriteLine("Pattern Name : " + line2);
                                            patternwritten = true;
                                        }
                                        dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " + "           " + line.Trim());
                                    }
                                    counter++;
                                }
                                //FilePath.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                                counter = 1;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It isn't clear to me what the actual question is... what isn't behaving as you expect? or what exactly do you want to happen that isn't?

Comment: @bala, could you please elaborate whats the exact problem you are facing....

Comment: @Marc Gravell:i have written a text in a file i dont know how to read that text file and read it line by line...bcoz i have used a variable

Comment: @Ramesh Vel:i have written a text in a file i dont know how to read that text file and read it line by line...bcoz i have used a variable

Comment: @bala3569 - what has "used a variable" got to do with anything? You *appear* to be reading it line-by-line, via `ReadLine` - I'm still really unclear on what the question is here.

Comment: @Marc Gravell:I cant give like thisusing (var file = File.OpenText(dest1))

Comment: @Marc Gravell:System.IO.file.opentext(string) has some invalid arguments

Comment: @dest1 - well, `dest1` isn't a string... it wants a path. See Josh's reply. If you had posted that message in the original question we would have understood a **lot** more...

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Ya thats my mistake

Comment: @Marc Gravell:now it is saying The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\tp1391\Desktop\log\log1.txt' because it is being used by another process

Comment: @Marc Gravell:while writing itself i am reading that text file so it is showing this error..how to read that file after it finished writing

Comment: @Marc Gravell:Look at my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the filename in a variable like so:

```
string filename = Path.Combine(_logFolderPath, "log1.txt");
```

Then use it in the following lines:

```
var dest1 = File.AppendText(filename);
...
using (var file = File.OpenText(filename))
```

Then the rest should work as expected. In your code above you were trying to pass a StreamWriter to the File.OpenText method which is wrong.

Comment: @Josh Einstein:U understood my prob

Comment: @Josh Einstein:now it is saying The process cannot access the file 'C:\Documents and Settings\tp1391\Desktop\log\log1.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Comment: @Josh Einstein:while writing itself i am reading that text file so it is showing this error..how to read that file after it finished writing

Comment: Simultaneously reading and writing a text file is a bad idea. If you must do it (which you probably don't if you rethink your approach) then you would have to use the File.Open method that takes a FileShare option instead of using File.AppendText.

Comment: Your code is very hard to read but it looks like you're done with dest1 after writing to it so I would just close the stream when you're done with it. Then you don't have to worry about sharing the file access.

Answer (score 2):

You're not closing the file after writing to it, so your program still has an open handle to the file, which means that you can't open another handle to read from it.

This bit:

```
var dest1 = File.AppendText(filename);

dest1.WriteLine(line.Trim());
```

should be:

```
using (var dest1 = File.AppendText(filename))
{
    dest1.WriteLine(line.Trim());
}
```